# file sharing web site in asp.net like dropbox , currently all uploaded data stored on my machine but i want to store that on multiple machine?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, distributed-computing

i created web site and data base for that and works fine on single machine but now transform this on 2 machine in which website running on my PC but when end user upload the files it store on another PC ,so My PC will be middleware and end user does not know where the actually resource are lying?
so how to connect my Pc to anothere just for data storage ?